# Call caretRender on page load (React-Bootstrap-Table)

Tags: reactjs

I am working with React-BootStrap-Table, I have my own Sort and GetCaret Functions

e.g.  caretRender={this.getCaret}

This works fine except when the user leaves the page and returns.  I can save all the sort info (current sort and direction) and retrieve them but the sort indicator function (carentRender) only fires when a user clicks on the TableColumnHeader so it doesn't display on page load.

Is there any way to force caretRender to fire on a page load?

Comment: onload() { getcaret() }

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with setting the default sortName and SortOrder...and using functions to retrieve them from the saved state.   These get called everytime the table renders.

```
const options = {
sortName: this.getSortName(),
sortOrder: this.getSortOrder(),
```

}